# Assigning id to button in second form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms. The code below is from my first form.

```
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        if(f2.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            stringtype = "L";
            Cover cover = new Cover(_counter_,stringtype,datestart);
            cover.Text = "Cover Lead";
            cover.ShowDialog();
        }
        if(f2.DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            stringtype = "A";
            Cover cover = new Cover(_counter_, stringtype,datestart);
            cover.Text = "Cover Assistant";
            cover.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Is there a way to simplify this? Because I assigned the `dialogresult` with yes and no. All I want is when I click `button1`, it will give me `L` and when I `click` button2 it will give me `A`. I have already assigned that after I click the button, the form2 will close.

The second form `form2` is displayed as below.

[image]

Comment: i dont get it. you want  a messagebox that shows A or L based on selection when user clicks lead and ass buttons?

Comment: Instead of using a separate form you can just use a messagebox.DialogResult results =  MessageBox.Show("Cover", "My Messagebox", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (results == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
            }

Comment: You should use the DialogResult to tell whether the user pressed one of the buttons or used the close button to exit the form, and have a public "SelectedButton" property on Form2 which you can then query to see what button was pressed, if any.

Comment: @jdweng well, i think of that too, but i dont want the button display text yes  and no

Comment: @Badiparmagi no, more like return the value when iclick this button to mainform